# Unexpected behaviour with grep and dplyr tbl compared to data.frame

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, dplyr, grepl

Consider this example

```
library(dplyr)

simple_dat_df <- data.frame(num = 1:5, let = letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

grepl("[a-z]", simple_dat_df$let)
grepl("[a-z]", simple_dat_df[,"let"])

simple_dat_tbl <- data_frame(num = 1:5, let = letters[1:5])

grepl("[a-z]", simple_dat_tbl$let)
grepl("[a-z]", simple_dat_tbl[,"let"])
```

The first three `grepl` commands return `[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`. The last one only `[1] TRUE`.

I'd expect it to be the same. What is the intention? And how can the last statement also return a vector?

Comment: `simple_dat_tbl$let` is equivalent to `unname(unlist(simple_dat_tbl[,"let"]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a feature of `dplyr`. If you subset the `data_frame` to obtain one column, it does not simplify the output to a vector, which is standard behavior with `data.frame`s. See:

```
class(simple_dat_tbl$let)
[1] "character"
class(simple_dat_tbl[,"let"])
[1] "tbl_df"     "data.frame"
```

You can use `[[]]` if you want it to return a vector. See:

```
class(simple_dat_tbl[["let"]])
[1] "character"
```

See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/data_frames.html) for more information.